# Webpack and HTTP/2

Tags: webpack, http2

What is the best way to set up webpack with http/2? Currently I have cloudfront set to serve http/2. When I load content usually it works, but sometimes chrome gives me the error `net::ERR_SPDY_COMPRESSION_ERROR`.

Comment: What should webpack have to do with HTTP/2? webpack just bundles applications into HTML files, Javascript & Co. It isn't interested whether you serve them via HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, in the cloud, on an embedded device or elsewhere.

Comment: That's what I use to think also until I verified that my site works with HTTP/1 and not with HTTP/2. Also a larger discussion on it -
 https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1223